# A website that can test other websites

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, selenium, automated-tests

Is there a way, or is there a web site that can run test cases against another REST server?
On the "tester" website you'd say: do this PUT on this URI, using this authentication mechanism, using this JSON string, with this header, etc. If the result contains XYZ then consider it a success, otherwise consider it a failure...

Other users should be able to add new test cases and edit existing test cases.

I wanted to check before writing a combination of wiki, google app engine, selenium, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its not what you probably search for, but still probably worth the check: [SimpleTestIO](http://simpletest.io)

That project's goal is to be easier than Selenium and easy to use. In the future will be probably paid.

Disclaimer: I am not connected with the page, just found it while researching for Selenium alternatives